# UILabel preferredMaxLayout breaking self-sizing cells

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I found some really annoying problem with UILabel not working with AutoLayout.

I found multiple threads about this, but none of solutions worked for me.

```
class AudiosHeaderCell: CollectionViewCell<AudiosHeaderItemViewModel> {
    var label: UILabelPreferedWidth? {
        didSet {
            self.label?.textAlignment = .center
            self.label?.numberOfLines = 0
            self.label?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            self.label?.font = Font.Standard.size14
            self.label?.textColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x185B97)
        }
    }
    let labelLeftRightMargin = CGFloat(16)

    override func setupViews() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.label = UILabelPreferedWidth()
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.label!)
    }

    override func setupConstraints() {
        self.label?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: labelLeftRightMargin, bottom: 8, right: labelLeftRightMargin))
        }
    }

    override func bindViewModel(viewModel: AudiosHeaderItemViewModel) {
        self.label?.text = viewModel.text
    }
}

class UILabelPreferedWidth : UILabel {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            print("SET BOUNDS", bounds)
            if (bounds.size.width != oldValue.size.width) {
                self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            }
        }
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        print("updateConstraints", preferredMaxLayoutWidth, bounds)
        if(preferredMaxLayoutWidth != bounds.size.width) {
            preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.size.width
        }
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

I use a method to calculate the size of the cell like this:

```
func sizeForCellWithViewModel(_ viewModel: IReusableViewModel, fittingSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let cell = self.classRegistry.instances[viewModel.reuseIdentifier]!
    (cell as! ICollectionViewCell).setViewModel(viewModel)
    cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittingSize.width, height: fittingSize.height)
    cell.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    print("SIZE FOR ", cell, "FITTING ", fittingSize, "IS", cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(fittingSize))

    return cell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(fittingSize)
}
```

It works for multiple cells that has some images and other content, but it fails on such a simple problem like scaling to content of UILabel.

Problem I have is that `systemLayoutSizeFitting.width` returns size that is larger than `fittingSize.width` parameter I pass.

I've been debugging this long time and I found out that `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` is not updating properly, as bounds for this UILabel are going beyond cell frame - despite the constraints I use there.

Does anyone have a good solution for that ?

The only one I found is to use this on CollectionViewCell:

```
override var frame: CGRect {
    didSet {
        self.label?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.size.width - 32
    }
}
```

But I hate it because it forces me to synchronise that with constraints and it will be required to all other use-cases in my application to remember to copy that.
What I'm looking for is AutoLayout, Constraint only solution.

Comment: did you use autolayout ?

Comment: Yep I do - via SnapKit as you can see in code

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved by adding width constraint to the Cell's contentView:

```
func sizeForCellWithViewModel(_ viewModel: IReusableViewModel, fittingSize: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let cell = self.classRegistry.instances[viewModel.reuseIdentifier]!
    (cell as! ICollectionViewCell).setViewModel(viewModel)
    cell.contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fittingSize.width, height: fittingSize.height)
    cell.contentView.snp.removeConstraints()
    if fittingSize.width != 0 {
        cell.contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.width.lessThanOrEqualTo(fittingSize.width)
        }
    }
    if fittingSize.height != 0 {
        cell.contentView.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
            make.height.lessThanOrEqualTo(fittingSize.height)
        })
    }
    cell.contentView.setNeedsLayout()
    cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(fittingSize)
}
```

Seems that this somehow makes UILabel works and preferredWidth not going crazy.